# How to use All XAML Control in toolbox - Visual Studio 2012 Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, toolbox

I'm new in developing windows phone apps. I've tried using Ms Visual 2013 (WP 8.1) and in the toolbox we can use All Xaml Control, but when i want use Ms Visual 2012 (WP 8) i can't use all xaml control. So, is it possible to use all xaml control in Ms Visual 2012? because i want use Grid view etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can use GridView on WP8.

GridView is strictly a WIN8 (Store App) / WP8.1 runtime thing.  See minimum requirements here:

[MSDN GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx)

What you get in the tool box for 2012 is the available controls for WP 8.0 Silverlight.  If you want something like a GridView on WP8.0 then you either have to roll your own or install Windows Phone Toolkit using NuGet or get it here: [Windows Phone Toolkit Homepage](https://phone.codeplex.com/).

With some modification the `<LongListSelector>` and `<WrapPanel>` can emulate the GridView pretty well.